# Como generar un pdf correctamente de tablas anidadas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, dompdf

estoy intentando generar una pdf para imprimirlo como comprobante. Por facilidad lo hago mediante el uso de tablas. La situacion es que al tener tantas tablas anidadas el color de mis celdas estan saliendo de su area para abarcar otras celdas. Y al mismo tiempo deja un vacio en la celda donde se deberia renderizar.

Aqui pueden ver la imagen de como renderiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se ve en el explorador chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estes mi codigo HTMl para generar el archivo PDF con la libreria DOMPDF

```
<html>
   <head> </head>
   <body>
      <style type='text/css'>
        .t0 {
          font: 9px 'Helvetica';
          color: #404040;
        }

        td.detalle {
          border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle0 {
          border-top: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle1 {
          border-right: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle2 {
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle3 {
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle4 {
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
          font: 9px 'Helvetica';
        }

        td.footer {
          border-left: 1px solid;
          border-top: 1px solid;
          font: 9px 'Helvetica';
        }

        td.footer1 {
          border-right: 1px solid;
          border-top: 1px solid;
          font: 9px 'Helvetica';
        }

        td.footer2 {
          border-right: 1px solid;
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
          font: 9px 'Helvetica';
        }

        td.cabecera {
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
          border-right: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        td.cabdetalleleft {
          font-weight: bold;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
          background: #ddd;
          border-left: 1px solid;
          border-top: 1px solid;
        }

        td.cabdetallerigth {
          font-weight: bold;
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
          background: #ddd;
          border-right: 1px solid;
          border-top: 1px solid;
          border-left: 1px solid;
        }

        td.detalle5 {
          border-bottom: 1px solid;
        }

        td.text-bold {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
     </style>
      <div id='page_1'>
         <div class='dclr'></div>
         <div id='id_1'></div>
         <div id='id_2'>
            <br /><br />              
            <table cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' class='t0' style='width: 100%;font-size: 10px;'>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan='2' valign='top' style='text-align:center; width:30%;'><img src='%logo%' width='105' /> </td>
                     <td rowspan='1' style="width: 35%;"><b>Dirección : </b> %direccion_emisor% - %emisor_distrito% - %emisor_provincia% - %emisor_departamento% </td>
                     <td rowspan='3' style="width: 35%;">
                        <table cellpadding='7' cellspacing='0' class='t0' style='width: 100%;border:1px solid;'>
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td> &nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align='center' style='font: 11pt ' Calibri';'>R.U.C N° %ruc_emisor%</td>
                             </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td align='center' style='font: 14pt Calibri;background: #ddd;font-weight: bold;'>NOTA DE VENTA</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align='center' style='font: 11pt ' Calibri';'><b>%cotizacion_numero%</b></td>
                             </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td> &nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                       
                       <table cellpadding='7' cellspacing='0' style='width: 100%;border:1px solid;'>
                           <tbody>
                              <tr  style='font: 14pt Calibri;background: #ddd;font-weight: bold;'>
                                 <td align='center'>
                                   DIA
                                 </td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                   MES
                                 </td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                   AÑO
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align='center' style='font: 11pt ' Calibri';'>
                                  <b>29</b>
                                </td>
                                <td align='center' style='font: 11pt ' Calibri';'>
                                  <b>09</b>
                                </td>
                                <td align='center' style='font: 11pt ' Calibri';'>
                                  <b>2021</b>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                       
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan='2' align='left' valign='top'>
                       <b>Sucursal : </b>P.J. MIRAFLORES ALTO AV. V.R. HAYA 
                       <b>Telf : </b> %telefonoemisor%<br />
                       <b> Correo : </b> %email_emisor%<br />
                       <b>Web : </b>%web_emisor%
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td rowspan='1' align='center' valign='top' style='font: 10pt Calibri;;font-weight: bold;'>PRODUCTOS XXXX DE:<br/> XXXXXX</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />              
            <table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' class='t0' style='width: 100%;font-size: 10px;'>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width='65'></td>
                     <td width='5'></td>
                     <td width='245'></td>
                     <td width='65'></td>
                     <td width='80'></td>
                     <td width='115' colspan='3'></td>
                     <td width='5'></td>
                     <td width='152' colspan='2'></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td valign='top'>SEÑOR(ES)</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>%nombre_cliente%</td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>FECHA</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='2'>%fecha_emision%</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td valign='top'>%tipo_doc_ident%</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>%nro_doc_cli%</td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>CONDICIÓN DE PAGO</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='2'>%cond_pago%</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td valign='top'>DIRECCIÓN</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>%dir_cliente%</td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='3'>TIPO DE MONEDA</td>
                     <td valign='top'> : </td>
                     <td valign='top' colspan='2'>%moneda%</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />              
            <table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' class='t0' style='width: 100%;font-size: 10px;'>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width='60' align='center' class='cabdetalleleft'>CÓDIGO</td>
                     <td width='35' align='center' class='cabdetalleleft'>UNID.</td>
                     <td width='50' align='center' class='cabdetalleleft'>CANTIDAD</td>
                     <td colspan='2' width='320' align='center' class='cabdetalleleft'>DESCRIPCIÓN</td>
                     <td width='75' align='center' class='cabdetalleleft'>PRECIO DE VENTA UNITARIO</td>
                     <td width='75' align='center' class='cabdetallerigth' colspan='2'>PRECIO DE VENTA TOTAL</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td align='center' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='center' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td class='detalle' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle1' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  %comp_detalle% 
                  <tr>
                     <td align='center' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='center' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td class='detalle' colspan='2'>%observacion%</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle'>&nbsp;</td>
                     <td align='right' class='detalle1' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class='detalle detalle0 detalle5' colspan='5' rowspan='2'>%monto_letras%</td>
                     <td class='footer detalle5'>TOTAL :</td>
                     <td class='detalle2 detalle5' valign='bottom'>%s_moneda%</td>
                     <td class='footer1 detalle5' align='right' valign='bottom'>%total%</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <br/>              
            <table width='732' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' class='t0' style='width: 732px;font-size: 10px;'>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td style='text-align:left;'>Cta Cte MN BCP: XXX-XXXXXX-X-XX</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td style='text-align:left;'>Cta Detracciones: XX-XXX-XXXXXX</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Cual es el truco con esta libreria? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Realmente no veo que se traslapen las columnas, ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir?